# Haw to pass an id to server side method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `gridview` and I want to keep the headers as `hyperlink` to navigate the link in new tab

```
<asp:TemplateField
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnk" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# GettheNavigateUrl()%>'>Header</asp:HyperLink>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    ...........

protected string GettheNavigateUrl()
{
        return "http://www.google.com/";
}
```

Now I want to pass the id to the method. How to do it `'<%# GettheNavigateUrl(??)%>'`

Comment: What you want to do with Id? Just curious to know. And BTW it's not possible like this because this is one way data binding.

Comment: Still not clear why you need Id for that but you should do that in `RowDataBound` event as demonstrated by Ganesh.

Comment: Which Id? Record Id?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in .aspx

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnk" runat="server" Target="_blank"  >Header</asp:HyperLink>
```

You can add RowDataBound  method as `GridView_RowDataBound`
`OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound"`

in code

```
protected string GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {

            HyperLink hyp = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hyp");
            hyp.NavigateUrl = "www.google.com" + hyp.ClientID;
            // hyp.ClientID is your id of control
        }
    }
```

Comment: `hlnk` doesnot exist in this context

Answer (score 0):

This will work with Jquery

```
NavigateUrl='<%# GettheNavigateUrl($(this).attr('id'))%>'>
```

Jquery is Third Party Library which helps you optimize js Code

or

Have a look at this link

http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/pass-querystring-parameter-with-navigaterurl-in-hyperlink-inside-a-gridview

Comment: What do you mean that will work with jquery, it shows that `$` doesnot exist

Comment: You need to have JQuery in order for `$` to exists.. this means that you don't have it..